# How did a question get migrated to IoT from here?

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration

I saw a dubious question, and it went on hold which is fine, but it ended up at

https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/4657/how-rude-is-it-to-put-feet-on-a-table-in-public

And that's really strange. According to [the revisions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/149425/revisions), it was migrated away by two people, one a mod.

I believe we have a very limited number of migration targets.  Surely IoT is not one of them?

Answer (score 3):

I made a mistake moving that question. One little slip of a finger.
Most of the time moves like that get rejected without us asking them to do anything, so I wait a little before asking them to reject it, (which will move it back.) And then it can be moved to where I intended it to go, interpersonal skills.

As mods we can move questions to a lot of Stack Exchange sites, which are listed alphabetically.

The second person mentioned had voted to close, whatever reason they mention, once a close vote has been decided all people who voted to close are mentioned as part of the team closing for that reason.

Added:
In the end it got rejected on both of the sites and is now closed as off topic.

Comment: I didn't know mods can move to anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure 'anywhere' but certainly to a lot of places.

Comment: @KateGregory after all, we are *Travel* mods.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this. Thanks for bringing this up.